# Do classes like UndefinedObject behave like a singleton in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am learning Pharo and I want to understand if classes/objects like nil which belongs to UndifnedObject class have only 1 instance and act like a singleton, or is a new instance made every time we have a nil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbol `nil` refers to the single instance of `UndefinedObject`. You will find the same for `true` and `false` (sole instances of `True` and `False` respectively).

Comment: Thank you, I also wondered about true and false and you answered that as well.